# Use of area under the curve to compare treatments with count ordinal data over time

Tags: survey, ordinal-data, auc

I am working on questionnaire data, looking into bimonthly responses where "improvement" and "worsening" for different health parameters is recorded as counts or frequencies for a Treatment and Control group. The number of responders varies and the answers are generally not consistent over time, i.e. a responder does not always report "improvement".
I was wondering if the area under the curve for counts of responses over time  can be used to compare "improvement" and "worsening" between treatment groups?
I have seen the use of AUC for count data in epidemiology but not sure what the interpretation may be?

Comment: In what sense is this an "area"? You have counts at discrete time points that don't represent any particular duration of response or non-response. It's not clear to me how you'd turn that into an area under the curve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.